# Gurobi is not Minimizing the Objective function

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, operations-research

The problem is as follows:

Let `predict = [15, 15, 17, 16, 14, 15, 16, 14, 14, 22]`  be a list of numbers. I want a sequence of number `x = [x0,x2,x3,....,x9]` such that

`|x[0] - predict[0]| + |x[1] - predict[1]| + ...+ |x[9]-predict[9]|`

is minimum. The constraints are  `|x[i]-x[i+1]| <= 1 for i = 0 to 9`.  I wrote a code in python3 at jupyter notebook as follows:

```
original = [16, 15, 16, 15, 15, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15]
predict = [17, 15, 17, 16, 14, 13, 15, 14, 16, 24]
varlen = len(original)

import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
model = gp.Model()
I = range(varlen) 

x = model.addVars(I, vtype = GRB.INTEGER, name = "x")
y = model.addVars(I, vtype = GRB.INTEGER, name = "y")  
z = model.addVars(I, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="z")

#Adding objective function sum of z[i] = sum|y[i]| = sum |x[i]-predict[i]|
model.setObjective(gp.quicksum(z[i] for i in I), GRB.MINIMIZE)

model.addConstrs(z[i] == gp.abs_(y[i]) for i in I)
model.addConstrs(y[i] == (x[i]-predict[i]) for i in I)

#constraint |x[i] - x[i+1]| <= diff
model.addConstrs(x[i]-x[i+1] <= diff for i in range(varlen-1))
model.addConstrs(x[i]-x[i+1] >= -diff for i in range(varlen-1))
model.params.outputflag = 0

model.optimize()
temp = model.x
out = [0]*len(x)
for i in range(len(out)):
    out[i] = int(temp[i])
print(out)
print(model.ObjVal)
```

Output:
 `[17, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]`

`36.0`

But `x = original = [16, 15, 16, 15, 15, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15]` satisfies all the constraints and gives `ObjVal = 17` which is less than `36.0`.

That means the code is not minimizing the given objective function. I could not figure out what's wrong with the code. I am a begineer to gurobi, if you guys can help then it would be great.
Thanks for any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the signature of the `addVars` method:

```py
model.addVars(*indexes, lb=0.0, ub=GRB.INFINITY, obj=0.0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="")
```

i.e., the default lower bound for each variable is `0`. Consequently, we have `y[i] == x[i] - predict[i] >= 0`, which implies that `x[i]` is not allowed to be smaller than `predict[i]`.

By removing the lower bounds on the variables via

```py
x = model.addVars(I, lb=-1*GRB.INFINITY, vtype = GRB.INTEGER, name = "x")
y = model.addVars(I, lb=-1*GRB.INFINITY, vtype = GRB.INTEGER, name = "y")
z = model.addVars(I, lb=-1*GRB.INFINITY, vtype = GRB.INTEGER, name = "z")
```

you will obtain a solution with objective value 11.